# What's going on here?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, revisions-list

I was looking at an answer, I went for its [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3073819/revisions) and... 
The Revision#3 looks really strange... I don't have much time to try to investigate what is the reason for that.. But I'd like, because I've never seen other issue like this in SO before.

### Firefox 3.6.3 :

[image: Looking weird in FF]

### Internet Explorer 7:

[image: even worse than in FF]

### LINK:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3073819/revisions

PS: I suppose this could be an issue generated when decoding from this plain text to html.. Is SO having problems whith some text-formattings?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bug to me.

If you look at the [source of that revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46004eca-9603-4535-b70d-2e5304459054/view-source), you will notice that the poster used:

```
>    * Example
```

Which normally produces the following output:

> - Example

The default viewer handles this correctly, but the viewer for the revisions is probably a bit different and can't handle this kind of markdown.

This is a [supported feature of markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote), however in their examples they show it being done with only a single space (rather than 4):

```
> * Example
```

... which produces the same HTML:

> - Example

I <strike>will modify this post in 5 minutes</strike> modified to see if the same problem occurs here.

Nope, I wasn't able to reproduce it with this post.

---

> - Test

Test

> - Test

Answer (score 2):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm.

We're currently testing it here on Meta; once we're certain there are no problems, it will go out to the other sites as well. Your example was one of those I tested, and it is handled correctly by the new version.

Comment: New revision diff, eh? Does any of it [address the issues over at Mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits)?

Comment: Nope, those things have nothing to do with each other (LaTeX is rendered client side, the diffing happens on the server)

Answer (score 1):

Even more fun in Chrome in OS X!

[Chrome formatting fun! http://s179842339.onlinehome.us/chromeformattingfun.png](http://s179842339.onlinehome.us/chromeformattingfun.png)
<sub>NOTE: This is only an answer because of the inability to put inline images in comments; probably a good thing.</sub>