# Wrong formatting after edit

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown

I've edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399473/c-send-tcp-packet) and removed most some of the markup. But as you can see in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4399473/revisions) suddenly the whole question turned bold.

I didn't realize this so there was no further edit from me. But I don't see any reason why the whole thing turned bold, If I look at the source, everything is okay, if I edit my revision, everything is normal.

What happened here? Did miss something?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54262/whats-going-on-here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46334/revision-bug-bad-formating-closed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm.

We're currently testing it here on Meta; once we're certain there are no problems, it will go out to the other sites as well. Your example was one of those I tested, and it is handled correctly by the new version.