# Revisions overly italicizes text

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

I was looking at the [revisions of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6003144/revisions), and it occurred to me that there are unclosed `<em>` tags in the HTML code that cause a large portion of the text to be italic (namely, from somewhere in point 3's code to the end of the post).

Comment: See also: [Really weird (bad, confusing) version diff.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff), [What's going on here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54262/whats-going-on-here), [Revision bug, bad formating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46334/revision-bug-bad-formating), and plenty of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm.

We're currently testing it here on Meta; once we're certain there are no problems, it will go out to the other sites as well. Your example was one of those I tested, and it is handled correctly by the new version.